# How to protect private key for client cert in machine store? Is it acceptable for it to be exportable?

Tags: x.509, .net

Is it acceptable to store a client cert's private key as exportable in the computer's certificate store?

I have a .NET desktop app that installs client certificates in local machine\personal. The certificates are generated by a protected API. The certs are used to authenticate service calls by another .NET desktop application.

If the private keys are not marked as exportable, then the second desktop application is not able to access them unless the account that it is run under is given access permissions, or the application is run as an administrator. If access permissions were to be granted, this would need to be done programmatically and probably without additional user interactions. This would be complicated by the fact that the cert installer application runs with elevated privileges which mean it is ignorant of the user's account - so it doesn't know what account would need to be assigned the permissions.

If the private keys are marked as exportable then they could be protected with a password. Then the application that makes use of the certs would need to use the password to access them. However this would be a paradoxical solution because the client application has no way to authenticate itself to access the private key - until it can access the private key.

If it is not acceptable to store certificate with an exportable private key, then how could you avoid it in the scenario I've described? If it is, then how would you detect or protect against the certificate theft?

Comment: Windows certificate store can store the private key as non-exportable and without password. You will need to change some registries. If you can do that, you will be able to access private key via crypto API windows.

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to add it so that it is not exportable, but doing so results in the application that uses it needing to run under administrative privileges to access it. I was thinking about making it non-exportable and trying to programmatically grant access to it to authenticated users. Would there be value in this?

Comment: Create a non-admin user for your application. Import private key into the user cert store (Personal) not the system store. Then your application running from that user will be able to access the certificate and private key.

Comment: Thanks. Iirc I used the machine store because I needed to run the cert installer app as an admin and therefore it was ignorant of what user to install the cert for. Don't remember what specifically required the elevated privileges. Probably installing a root cert to the trusted store. I might revisit it.

Comment: This link will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171117/import-pfx-file-into-particular-certificate-store-from-command-line

Comment: "Create a non-admin user for your application. Import private key into the user cert store (Personal) not the system store. Then your application running from that user will be able to access the certificate and private key." - Unfortunately this appears to be incorrect. After adding the certificate there with the private key marked as not exportable, the process is unable to access the private key even when running as an administrator. I've checked that the process is running as the user that is expected.

Comment: What parameters are you using to access the private key? I've actually done this using curl and capi on windows machine.

Comment: Apologies - I have it working now! I had set the storage flag to store the private key in the machine store. Once I changed that to the user store it is now accessing the key without issue from the app without elevation or requiring the cert to be marked as exportable. Thank you - you have answered my question. Would you please add it as an answer so that I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion in the comments:

Create a non-admin user for your application. Import private key into the user cert store (Personal) not the system store. Then your application running from that user will be able to access the certificate and private key.